# как удалить атрибут через делегирование событий?

Tags: javascript, события

```js
list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let attr = target.getAttribute('style', '');

  if (target.tagName == 'LI') {
    target.style.color = 'red'; //добавили
  } else if (attr) {
    attr.removeAttribute('style'); //не получилось удалить))
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li my-attr="1">1</li>
  <li my-attr="2">2</li>
  <li my-attr="3">3</li>
  <li my-attr="4">4</li>
  <li my-attr="5">5</li>
  <li my-attr="6">6</li>
  <li my-attr="7">7</li>
  <li my-attr="8">8</li>
  <li my-attr="9">9</li>
  <li my-attr="10">10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вы берёте значение аттрибута (строку) и у него пытаетесь удалить аттрибут о_0?

Answer (score 1):

Вы ошибочно в теле второго условия `else-if` обращались к `attr.removeAttribute`.
А вторая ошибка в том, что первое условие выполнялось всегда и выполнение не доходило до условия, в котором удалялся атрибут.

```js
list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    let target  = e.target;
    let currentColor = target.style.color;
    
    if ( target.tagName == 'LI' ) {    
      target.style.color = ( currentColor === "red" ) ? "black" : "red";
    }
    
/* 
    if(target.tagName == 'LI' && !attr){
        target.style.color = 'red'; //добавили
    } else if(attr){
        target.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
*/

});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li my-attr="1">1</li>
    <li my-attr="2">2</li>
    <li my-attr="3">3</li>
    <li my-attr="4">4</li>
    <li my-attr="5">5</li>
    <li my-attr="6">6</li>
    <li my-attr="7">7</li>
    <li my-attr="8">8</li>
    <li my-attr="9">9</li>
    <li my-attr="10">10</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: понял, понравился вариант target.tagName == 'LI' && !attr. Спасибо