# Смена цвета после клика

Tags: javascript, css

Есть столбец элементов сделанный через список. Как сделать так чтобы после клика по элементу он поменял цвет(фон) и если кликнуть на другой, то станет активный на который щёлкнули?

```css
.ben1{
  background-color: green;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: cadetblue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
    <li><div id="1">1</div></li>
    <li><div id="2">2</div></li>
    <li><div id="3">3</div></li>
    <li><div id="4">4</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Отвечал на подобный вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732136/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9/732143#732143)

Comment: Только если через `:active` псевдо-элемент. Так-как у `css` нет событий `click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { /*прокручиваем в цикле все элементы*/
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    /*при клике на элемент 
     */
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');

      /*удаляем у всех class active*/
    }
    this.classList.add('active'); /*добавляем class active по которому кликнули */
  })
}
```

```css
.ben1 {
  background-color: green;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="1">1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="2">2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="3">3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="4">4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!